# Library to detect in which programming language a code snippet is written

Tags: library, source-code

I am looking for a library that can detect in which programming language a code snippet is written. We can make the assumption that the code snippet is written in one language only.

E.g. for natural languages, I use the Python library [guess_language](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/guess_language-spirit):

```
>>> from guess_language import guess_language
>>> guess_language("Ces eaux regorgent de renégats et de voleurs.")
'fr'
>>> guess_language("Tienes que seguir tu corazón.")
'es'
>>> guess_language("いいえ！忍者がいます")
'ja'
>>> not guess_language("??")
True
```

If possible, it should return the probabilities of belonging to each programming language (e.g. for one code snippet given as input, the ouput could be 94% MATLAB, 30% Python, 5% Java, etc). Ideally, callable from Python/Java/C++ (descending order of preference), and free.

Comment: How will the snippets be presented to the library? You can use e.g. https://github.com/github/linguist if the snippets are in files.

Comment: Depending on the size of the snippet this can be almost impossible to do reliably, you could probably do as well with a few regex rules that look for defining characteristics.

Comment: @NeilSlater Ideally just pass as a string, but file is OK too. If I pass a file, I could just use [cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) (though it doesn't give probabilities).

Comment: @SteveBarnes Sure, hence the preference to have the probabilities of belonging to each programming language.

Comment: [Similar question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475033/detecting-programming-language-from-a-snippet)

Comment: @Gilles Thanks, nice reference! In retrospect maybe programming language detection needs more input than natural language detection.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Do you care in which language the actual library is written?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Not really, just if possible callable from Python/Java/C++ (descending order of preference).

Comment: A good choice to go for probability. The overlap between C & C++ is great, as is, to a lesser extent, C++ and Java. If you had compilable/runnable code, that would make it easier, but snippets are going to be tough print("hello world")

Answer (score 3):

Here's one [github/linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) that used by github, a ruby library.

Comment: Could you please give a usage example? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Here's another one [blackducksw/ohcount](https://github.com/blackducksw/ohcount/)
see the `ohcount_detect_language` function, its for `C`, also has `Ruby` and `Python` port.

Comment: Could you please give a usage example? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Another library [isagalaev/highlight.js](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js) for `JavaScript`, see the `highlightAuto` function in [highlight.js](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/blob/master/src/highlight.js) source, it gives 1 or 2 possible answer.

Comment: Could you please give a usage example? Thanks!